# replit not compatible with pyrebase? poetry

Tags: python, pyrebase

I am making a discord bot on replit and I am trying to use the firebase db (realtime db). I ran into a problem where poetry says that it is not compatible with replit. Here is the error.

```
--> python3 -m poetry add pyrebase
Using version ^3.0.27 for Pyrebase

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

  SolverProblemError

  Because no versions of pyrebase match >3.0.27,<4.0.0
   and pyrebase (3.0.27) depends on requests (2.11.1), pyrebase (>=3.0.27,<4.0.0) requires requests (2.11.1).
  And because replit (3.2.4) depends on requests (>=2.25.1,<3.0.0)
   and no versions of replit match >3.2.4,<4.0.0, pyrebase (>=3.0.27,<4.0.0) is incompatible with replit (>=3.2.4,<4.0.0).
  So, because repl-python3-jerry-bot depends on both replit (^3.2.4) and Pyrebase (^3.0.27), version solving failed.

  at /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py:241 in _solve
      237│             packages = result.packages
      238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
      239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
      240│         except SolveFailure as e:
    → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
      242│ 
      243│         results = dict(
      244│             depth_first_search(
      245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes
exit status 1


Replit: Package operation failed.
```

I understand that it is saying that pyrebase isn't compatible with replit but is there any way to fix that?

Comment: `pyrebase`'s dependencies have been declared in a very strict, incompatible way. (Most of the recent issues for it are related to that. https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/pulls) It also hasn't been updated in 4 years. Maybe look at some other library, or if you can find a more recent fork...

Comment: I looked on firebase documentation and the other ones were deprecated (not maintained and supported anymore). Do you know any other ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the side bar and went to packages. I then downloaded the latest pyrebase “pyrebase4” and then replit didn’t throw the error.

Comment: Great, you found a more recent fork then :)